# Expo Project Error when using expo start: Could not connect to development server

Tags: react-native, expo

I used expo init to create a project and was using expo start and I got the following error:
node.exe : Cannot determine which native SDK version your project uses because the module `expo` is not installed. Please install it with `yarn add expo` and try again.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

and here is my expo diagnostics output:

```
Expo CLI 3.17.15 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Windows 10 10.0.18362
    Binaries:
      Node: 13.12.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
      npm: 6.14.4 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: Version  3.6.0.0 AI-192.7142.36.36.6308749
```

What can I do to fix this? Let me know if there is any other info that I need to post. Thanks for any help!

Comment: update your expo-cli and create a new project and try `expo start`

Comment: That worked, thank you!